# Swift switch unwrap type match pattern

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to unwrap a type match within a switch statement?

I want to be able to do this...

```
let genericVC = getGenericVC() 
switch genericVC {
  case if let specialVC = genericVC as? specialVC: 
    specialVC.dospecialstufff()
}
```

What I currently have is this..

```
let genericVC = getGenericVC() 
switch genericVC {
  case is specialVC: 
    guard let specialVC = genericVC as? SpecialVC else { return }
    specialVC.dospecialstufff()
}
```

I want to remove the extra line of unwrapping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the syntax you're looking for:

```
switch genericVC {
case let specialVC as SpecialVC:
    specialVC.doSpecialStuff()
default:
    break
}
```